# opening google map in a tab in android not working

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs

I'm trying to open a google map application I did in a tab but its not working, it keep getting the force close message when I run it. I created the main activity file[TabtestingActivity] which creates the tabs [HelloGoogleActivity class contains the map code and it works fine without tabs]

```
public class TabstestingActivity extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HelloGoogleActivity.class);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabOne");  
    spec.setContent(intent); 
    spec.setIndicator("Tab One",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tabselect)); 
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

if I create a class which only has a text in it it works fine with tabs but when I add the map class it stops working.
This is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >  

<TabWidget
 android:id="@android:id/tabs"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<FrameLayout
 android:id="@android:id/tabcontent       
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="my key"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

is there any problem with my main.xml?

This is the logcat:

```
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tabtest/com.example.tabtest.TabstestingActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at com.example.tabtest.TabstestingActivity.onCreate(TabstestingActivity.java:15)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     ... 11 more
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:238)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     ... 22 more
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:282)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:255)
10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303):     ... 26 more
```

Comment: Please post the exception you are seeing in logcat with your question

Comment: Noticed you have a redundant layout_weight on the mapview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trace is pretty clear,

```
"10-26 00:47:10.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(303): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity."
```

You can't use the MapView outside of a `MapActivity`.